# I'm using unicode in a pseudo-element in my menu items, is it possible to remove it from the first menu item only?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, icons

I'm using the unicode \25C6 for the black solid diamond in my menu as a spacer between labels. I used the before pseudo-element per a thread found here on Stack Overflow. I searched here for about an hour but what I'm looking to do I might not be searching for with the right wording.

I'm only using the out of box Twenty-Twelve theme from Wordpress with a child theme. I did find some other similar questions about removing particular menu item icons, but I haven't found one that works for me. I just want to remove or "display:none" the fist icon or the last if someone thinks ::after is better to use.

I have tried adding it to the .nav-menu li but that makes it clickable and possibly a problem. I hope I've add the link properly be to the site, apologies if not.

This is the site http://vangurubros.com/

This is what I've tried to get the unicode to work

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu ::before {
content: "\25C6";
list-style: none;
font-size: 1.15em;
color: #cc8040;
margin: 0 20px 0 0px; 
}

.nav-menu li ::before {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible through css.

Use `:not(:first-child)` pseudo element/class (whatever)

```css
ul.nav-menu li:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "\25C6";
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    color: #cc8040;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0px;
}
ul li{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-amenu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-24 current_page_item menu-item-58"><a href="http://vangurubros.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-56"><a href="http://vangurubros.com/media/">Media</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-57"><a href="http://vangurubros.com/news/">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href="http://vangurubros.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Try this

Comment: great, I will run this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code like this:

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu li::before {
       content: "\25C6";
       list-style: none;
       font-size: 1.15em;
       color: #cc8040;
       margin: 0 20px 0 0px; 
    }
    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu li:first-child::before {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I would have marked both solutions answered as both work as needed perfectly, much appreciation.